# How to check if admin is logged in in a custom php file?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, security

I have a custom php file (Not a template file) or included in **function.php**.

I want to check if the user is logged in, Or the current user is an admin.

Does WordPress uses a specific `cookie` or something I could check?

file.php:

```
//Check if the current user is an admin.
if(){

}else{
    echo 'You are not admin';
    exit();
}
```

That file connects and updates the DB, And the data is posted from an Ajax request, So I want to make sure that the data is posted from the admin.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

[`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) is Wordpress's function for checking if a user is logged in or not. As for checking certain role's, last I researched there are only method's for checking users' permissions, not roles. But you can manually check with [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_get_current_user), which returns a the current user and accessing their roles with `$user->roles` (with `$user` being the returned user).

Comment: The php file is not a template file, not index.php or similar file, Not included in functions.php

Comment: @Dan from [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files) question on the Wordpress Stack Exchange, it looks like you can import those functions by requiring the `wp-load.php` file. You'll need to know where that is in relation to your php file.